# Pulling a single variable off a webview in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am 1 week into "brand new" to iOS. I am using x-code to create a view based app. Now using a web view I need to pull a variable from a hidden tag on the webpage and send it to native code. So how do I do this:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      **this varSendText**
        varSendText = document.getElementById("sendtextcoupon").value;
        if (varSendText == "1")..........
```

That is the goal but obviously not the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method of the `UIWebView`.

```
NSString *varSendText = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"return varSendText;"];
```

Just make sure the variable is global and the AJAX response has been received. You can also check this by using the above method and simple Javascript.

Class Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I was just about to post much the same thing, with this helpful link:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:

Comment: ah I see.  Objective C seems daunting at first glance so I need relative examples. This helped.  Which is why I love this community. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you need, but you can execute arbitrary javascript on a web view using

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script]
```

If `script` were something along the lines of:

```
@"return varSendData;"
```

That would do it in a normal case.  I'm not sure how the xmlhttprequest callback makes it different.  I'm not up on my ajax.  I assume you'll have to find some way to wait until the call succeeds.

**Edit**:  Somebody beat me to the punch apparently.  So there you go.  We've all suggested the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call **OUT** of your UIWebView into the app (which is what I think you're asing, vs **INTO** your UIWebView which is what the other current answers are addressing), you have to kick off a page-load from your content, either using javascript, or some user interaction like a hyperlink being followed.  Your app can cancel the page load so that the page doesn't actually navigate away.  You can pass data out as parameters on the page load request url.  You cant get any 'return value', but you can use what others have suggested (calling `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`) to pass data back in based on the result of whatever action you took for the pageLoad request.

The page load request is intercepted by your UIWebViewDelegate method:

`- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`

javascript to kick off the page load request can be something like this:

```
document.location = 'command://dosomething?param1=something&param2=more'
```

Here's a a page that has a more complete sample, in the section titled 'Javascript communicating back with Objective-C code':

http://www.codingventures.com/2008/12/using-uiwebview-to-render-svg-files/

Comment: Very Interesting.  This looks like a good article I'll read it over the weekend.  Thanks

Comment: sorry I was so new to this community and didn't have email alerts set up for answers.  I was close to getting this to work but not for this particular problem.  Then I ran out of time.  So after I done going through my and responding to all my stackoverflow responses I may revisit it.  Thanks